# Python 3.8 paramiko ssh, problem executing command

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I'm fairly new to coding with Python (and coding in general) and I'm having an issue in getting a command to execute during an SSH session using paramiko.  My code I'm using is as follows:

```
    from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
    import time

    client = SSHClient()
    client.load_host_keys('C:\ssh\id_rsa')
    time.sleep(5)
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    time.sleep(5)
    client.connect('192.168.2.138', username='pi-star', password='******')
    time.sleep(5)
    with open('C:\WeatherPro\Final_Page.txt') as fnlpage:
        datapage = fnlpage.read()
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(datapage)
    time.sleep(5)
    client.close()
```

This is to SSH from a Windows 10 Pro machine into a Raspberry Pi with a MMDVM hat (addon ham radio transceiver device) running Pi-Star (a raspbian\debian based operating system - GUI).  I am using it to send out a POCSAG page to a pager every 10 minutes.  The Final_Page.txt is a file that I'm creating with previous code and contains the linux terminal command I want to execute.  Reason for creating the text file is part of the information executed in the command updates about every minute.  This is the exact text that is written in the text file and the exact way the linux command needs to be structured (including the quotes):

sudo RemoteCommand 7642 page 1246587 "T: 91.2,  H: 42.5,  BP: 29.39,  PA: 1551,  CF: 1.0103,  DA: 2363,  WG: 64.93,  ET: 8.904"

The information inside the double quotation marks is what is changing about every minute and is the actual page that appears on the pager screen (it is info from a racing weather station).  If I eliminate the "with open" and ".read()" lines and use this line of code instead, it will execute the command and send the page correctly:

```
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo RemoteCommand 7642 page 1246587 "T: 91.2,  H: 42.5,  BP: 29.39,  PA: 1551,  CF: 1.0103,  DA: 2363,  WG: 64.93,  ET: 8.904"')
```

If I try to execute the command as I have in the original code, with the "with open" and ".read()" of the text file, nothing happens.  Any other ideas on what I could do to get the information that's updated frequently inserted into the command and get it to execute properly?

Thank you very much for any help,
Ryan W.

P.S.-The sleep time is just to give time for each process to execute as the Raspberry Pi isn't very fast and has trouble when there is no break in between.

Comment: If the command works, if you specify it as literal string, then you do not have [tag:ssh]/[tag:paramiko] question, but merely a problem with reading the local file correctly – I'd guess that the file has Windows line endings and the command fails due to the CR character.

Comment: Thank you Martin Prikryl.  I didn't think of the carriage return.  I will look into that.  Ryan W.